# Specify l2tpv3 ethernet's CircuitID and DigestHash in linux

Tags: linux-networking, mikrotik, l2tp

How can I Create a l2tpv3 tunnel in linux and specify circuit id and digest hash (tunnel between linux and mikrotik)